# Need to share data from (A) thread to (B) Thread using +ios (objective c or swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, swift3

I need to share data from 1 thread to another running thread. it's possible in ios(objective c or swift). If its possible then anyone please suggest me.

- I have A-thread & B-Thread both are running parallel.
- In A-thread have (XYZ Object).
- Need to pass on B-Thread in running process.

  Suggest me best solution or any blogs, tutorial, example etc....

Comment: can you specify what exactly you want do? i mean say for example,  do you want to pass the data from background thread to main thread? something like that ?

Comment: @Pi Threads Both thread are running on background

Comment: Don't use threads. It's 2017 already! Use dispatch queues instead.

Comment: Did you get answer to this question, please write answer here as we have same question.

Answer (score 1):

Both A and B can refer to a class containing this variable. You can then make this variable volatile, and this means that changes to that variable are immeditately visible in both threads.

See [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197/index.html)  for more info

> Volatile variables share the visibility features of synchronized, but none of the atomicity features. This means that threads will automatically see the most up-to-date value for volatile variables. They can be used to provide thread safety, but only in a very restricted set of cases: those that do not impose constraints between multiple variables or between a variable's current value and its future values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a model class of type `NSObject`. this model class will contain data as a singleton object. that singleton object can be accessed from anywhere by retaining the data within different threads. You atomic property, if you want to make thread safe reading.